# Add new object to reducer array in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

Im trying to make a simple forum widget, i need to get comments the get their children, what i want to do is to add the new array i get when i request children in to the reducer in a particular position. I have tried many things but i cant seem to make it work this is my reducer:

```
export default function content(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CONTENT_FETCH_REQUESTED:
            return {...state, loading: true};
        case CONTENT_FETCH_SUCCEEDED:
            return {...state, saving: false, content: action.content};
        case CHILDREN_FETCH_SUCCEEDED:
            return {
                ...state,
                content: [...state.content[action.index], ...state.content[action.index].children, action.content]
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel its the issue of mutating the state. Hope this helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268417/react-failed-to-add-item-to-list-in-redux/52268510#52268510

Comment: It would be helpful to see what each object inside of content looks like.

Comment: Likewise for the action.